# Value didn't set selectOneMenu to ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu that loads anothers in demand. See:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Tabela: *" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuTabela"
                    converter="entityConverter"
                    value="#{orcamentoMB.tabelaSelecionada}" effect="fade"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="A Tabela é obrigatória">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uma Tabela" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{orcamentoMB.tabelas}" var="tabela"
                        itemLabel="#{tabela.nome}" itemValue="#{tabela}" />
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="selectOneMenuProcedimento" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputText value="Procedimento: *" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuProcedimento"
                    disabled="#{orcamentoMB.tabelaSelecionada == null}"
                    converter="entityConverter" filter="true"
                    filterMatchMode="contains"
                    value="#{orcamentoMB.itemTabelaProcedimentoSelecionado}"
                    effect="fade" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="O procedimento é obrigatório">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um Procedimento" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{orcamentoMB.tabelaSelecionada.itens}"
                        var="item" itemLabel="#{item.procedimento.nome}"
                        itemValue="#{item}" />
                    <p:ajax event="change"
                        update="localAplicacao, selectOneMenuDente,selectOneMenuFace" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputText value="Local Aplicação: *" />
                <h:outputText id="localAplicacao"
                    value="#{orcamentoMB.itemTabelaProcedimentoSelecionado.procedimento.localAplicacao.descricao}" />

                <h:outputText value="Dente: *" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuDente" converter="entityConverter"
                    filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
                    disabled="#{orcamentoMB.itemTabelaProcedimentoSelecionado.procedimento == null || orcamentoMB.itemTabelaProcedimentoSelecionado.procedimento.dentesAsList.size() == 0}"
                    value="#{orcamentoMB.denteSelecionado}" effect="fade">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um Dente" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems
                        value="#{orcamentoMB.itemTabelaProcedimentoSelecionado.procedimento.dentesAsList}"
                        var="dente" itemLabel="#{dente.descricao}" itemValue="#{dente}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputText value="Face: *" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuFace" converter="entityConverter"
                    disabled="#{orcamentoMB.itemTabelaProcedimentoSelecionado.procedimento.facesAplicacaoAsList.size() == 0 || orcamentoMB.itemTabelaProcedimentoSelecionado == null}"
                    value="#{orcamentoMB.faceSelecionada}" effect="fade">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uma Face" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems
                        value="#{orcamentoMB.itemOrcamento.itemTabelaProcedimento.procedimento.facesAplicacaoAsList}"
                        var="face" itemLabel="#{face.descricao}" itemValue="#{face}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

The "selectOneMenuTabela" and "selectOneMenuProcedimento" works fine, the value are setted in ManagedBean, but the others not.

When i try to execute this commandButton bellow:

```
<p:commandButton value="Incluir" icon="ui-icon-plus" process="@this"
                    disabled="#{orcamentoMB.bean.situacao.codigo != 'AGUARDANDO_ACEITACAO'}"
                    update=":formManterOrcamento:tabViewManterOrcamento:tabProcedimentos,:formManterOrcamento:panelTotais"
                    actionListener="#{orcamentoMB.addItemOrcamento}" />
```

THe value inside "denteSelecionado" is null, and the values inside "selectOneMenuFace" aren't loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are having `p:ajax event="change"`on first two selectOneMenu they are being submitted that is why you are getting those value. To process them on click of commandButton add those component ids to process attribute along with @this like process like `process="@this,selectOneMenuFace,selectOneMenuDente,.."`

If the component is `disabled` or `readOnly` then they won't be processed.

Hope this helps